# Print data of one column differently

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**Controller Code:**

```
 $this->loadModel('Social');
    $this->set('social', $this->Social->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Social.id','Social.semfieldvalue'))));
```

**View Code:**

```
<?php foreach ($social as $socials): ?>
                <td><?php echo $socials['Social']['semfieldvalue']; ?></td>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I get all field value of semi-field column.

But now in my view file I want to print. 1st row value at different place and 2nd row value at diff place.. so how to do this in cakephp.

my out put when i `<?print_r($social); ?>`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Social] => Array ( [id] => 1 [semfieldvalue] => http://www.facebook.com/new ) ) [1] => Array ( [Social] => Array ( [id] => 2 [semfieldvalue] => http://www.twitter.com/new ) ) [2] => Array ( [Social] => Array ( [id] => 3 [semfieldvalue] => http://www.linkedin.com/new ) ) [3] => Array ( [Social] => Array ( [id] => 4 [semfieldvalue] => http://www.google.com/new ) ) ) http://www.facebook.com/new
```

so i got all value but i want to print id 1 at diff place and id 2 at diff place in same view file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to print 1st value in Array : Use

```
echo $social[0]['Social']['semfieldvalue'];
```

to print 2nd val

```
echo $social[1]['Social']['semfieldvalue'];
```